# the word for the wrong actor

Tags: vocabulary

what is the one word substitute for"he or she is the wrong actor for that part or role?

Does misfit or unfit suit the purpose?
 I would like to know the noun for the sentence

Comment: Verb or noun? 'miscast' is the verb

Comment: @Mitch He might be thinking about the verb "miscast", but believe it to be a noun or an adjective, due to the way it is often used, "he is miscast". Considering (based on the OP's name) he is probably someone with English as a second language, this might be the case.

Comment: @A. Kvåle The intercategorial polyseme 'miscast' [n]  _is_ in the lexicon. How often it is used in the acting sense I couldn't say. Perhaps an OED subscriber could add some clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to say

> Kim is the wrong actor for that part or role.

is

> Kim is miscast in that role.

Lexico has [**miscast**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/miscast) as a verb, above  is the adjectival use of the verb.

> **miscast**
>   VERB
>
> **1** Allot an unsuitable role to (an actor)
>   *he is badly miscast in the romantic lead*

Lexico does not classify **miscast** as a noun and it would be very unusual to say

> Kim is a miscast.

as if there is a similarity with [**misfit**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/misfit), which anyway is not used in this context.

Comment: Although it doesn't refer to a *person*, you can also use **miscasting** as a noun : *It was a miscasting.*